# Mailchimp unstyled form does not submit on the webpage

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, mailchimp

I have created a simple hardcoded popup with an unstyled Mailchimp form. But when I deploy it to a WordPress webpage through the "Insert Headers and Footers" plugin it does not work. When I test the code on an online HTML editor, then it works. I am trying to find out what is the problem, I presume that there is somewhere on the server-side something that is blocking the link to be clicked.

code for the popup:

```
<script>
    var element = document.getElementById("wrapper");

var t=setTimeout(openPopUp,3000);
function openPopUp() {
  element = document.getElementById("wrapper");
  element.style.visibility = "visible";
  element.style.opacity = "1";
}



/* Get all elements with class="close" */
function zatvori() {
  var x = document.getElementById("wrapper");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}

</script>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de-CH">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Newsletter XXX</title>
    <style>
        * {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            margin: 0;
            font-family: 'Roboto', Arial, sans-serif;
            line-height: 1.2;
            
        }
        

        #wrapper {
            position: relative;
            height: 950px;
            max-width: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
            background-size: cover;
            background-position: right;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            display: block;
            visibility: hidden;
            opacity: 0;
            -webkit-transition: opacity 0.7s;
            transition: opacity 0.7s;
            
        }

        #mask {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 430px;
            height: 950px;
            
            opacity: 0.5;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 0px 25px 0px rgba(255,255,255,1);
            -moz-box-shadow: 5px 0px 25px 0px rgba(255,255,255,1);
            box-shadow: 5px 0px 25px 0px rgba(255,255,255,1);
        }

        .content {
            position: absolute;
            width: 435px;
            height: auto;
            padding: 28px 25px;
            background-color: #82BB28;
            z-index: 1;

        }

        /* Style the close button (span) */
        .close {
            cursor: pointer;
            color:white;
            float: right;
            position: absolute;
            top: 5%;
            right: 2%;
            padding: 12px 16px;
            transform: translate(0%, -50%);
            }

            .close:hover {background: red;}

        div .text-1 p {
            text-transform: uppercase;
            font-weight: normal;
            font-size: 18px;
            margin: 0;
            line-height: 1.1;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            color: #000;
        }

        .text-spacing {
            letter-spacing: 1px;
        }

        .text-2 p {
            margin: 40px 0 30px 0;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            font-size: 19px;
            font-weight: bold;
            letter-spacing: 1px;
        }
        .text-3 {
            font-size: 12px;
            color: #A1A199;
        }

        .email-btn {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
        }

                    /* Full-width input fields */
            input[type=text], input[type=email] {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 15px;
            margin: 5px 0 22px 0;
            display: inline-block;
            border: none;
            background: #f1f1f1;
            }
        textarea {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 15px;
            margin: 5px 0 22px 0;
            display: inline-block;
            border: none;
            background: #f1f1f1;
        }

                /* Set a style for button */
        .button-form {
        background-color: #04AA6D;
        color: white;
        padding: 14px 20px;
        margin: 8px 0;
        border: none;
        cursor: pointer;
        width: 100%;
        opacity: 0.9;
        }

        .button-form:hover {
        opacity:1;
        }

        #ad-email {
            height: 36px;
            width: 65%;
            padding: 0px 14px;
            background-color: #fff;
            border: 1px solid #ababab;
            border-radius: 3px;
            font-size: 12px;
            color: #332c2c;
        }

        /*placeholder*/
        ::-webkit-input-placeholder {
            /* Chrome/Opera/Safari */
            font-size: 10px;
            color: #ababab;
        }

        ::-moz-placeholder {
            /* Firefox 19+ */
            font-size: 10px;
            color: #ababab;
        }

        :-ms-input-placeholder {
            /* IE 10+ */
            font-size: 10px;
            color: #ababab;
        }

        :-moz-placeholder {
            /* Firefox 18- */
            font-size: 10px;
            color: #ababab;
        }

        #send {
            width: 29%;
            height: 36px;
            background-color: #fff;
            border: 1px solid #000;
            border-radius: 3px;
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: 10px;
            color: #000000;
            cursor: pointer;
            transition: all 0.3s;
        }

        #send:hover {
            background-color: #332c2c;
            color: #fff;
        }

        .accept {
            position: relative;
            margin: 14px 0 35px 0;
        }

        #check {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left:0;
            opacity: 0;
        }

        .accept label {
            display: flex;
            cursor: pointer;
            font-size: 10px;
            line-height: 12px;
        }

        .checkbox-box {
            display: inline-block;
            width: 12px;
            height: 12px;
            background-color: #fff;
            border: 1px solid #332c2c;
        }

        #check:checked+label>.checkbox-box {
            background-color: #332c2c;
        }

        .checkbox-label {
            margin-left: 5px;
            width: calc(100% - 18px);
            line-height: 14px;
        }

        .checkbox-label a {
            color: #000;
            display: block;
        }

        .profit-1 {
            font-size: 20px;
            line-height: 25px;
        }

        ul.benefits {
            column-count: 2;
            margin-left: 15px;
            padding: 0;
        }

        li {
            width: 95%;
            font-size: 10px;
            line-height: 14px;
        }

        @media all and (max-width: 434px) {
            .content {
                width: 100%;
            }
        }

        @media all and (max-width: 387px) {

            .text-1 p, .text-2 p {
                font-size: 20px;
            }
        }

        @media all and (max-width: 379px) {

            .content {
                padding: 20px;
            }


            .text-2 p {
                margin: 20px 0 30px 0;
            }

            #inputs {
                position: relative;
                padding-bottom: 15px;
            }

            #ad-email {
                width: 100%;
            }

            #send {
                width: 50%;
                position: absolute;
                bottom: 0;
                left: 0;
            }

            .checkbox-label a {
                display: inline;
            }

            

            .profit {
                margin-top: 20px;
            }

            ul.benefits {
                column-count: 1;
            }

            li {
                width: 100%;
            }
        }

        @media all and (max-width: 324px) {
            .profit-1 {
                font-size: 16px;
                line-height: 20px;
            }

            .text-1 p {
                text-align: center;
            }

            .text-2 p {
                margin: 15px 0 20px 0;
                text-align: center;
            }

            #send {
                left: 50%;
                transform: translateX(-50%);
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <!-- width - 655 x height -450-->

    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="mc_embed_signup">
        <form action="https://ozg.us3.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=da98377a6d05e2f01558d3e04&id=67aaab10f0" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>

        <div id="mask"></div>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="text-1">
                <p>OZG - DER SPEZIALIST FÜR KOMPLETTAUSSTATTUNG IM<span class="close" onclick="zatvori()">X</span></p>
                <p class="text-spacing"> GESUNDHEITSWESEN</p>
            </div>

            <div class="text-2">
                <p>Haben Sie eine Anfrage oder möchten einen persönlichen Beratungstermin buchen?</p>
            </div>
            <!--
                <div id="inputs">
                <div class="email-btn">
                    <input type="email" name="#" placeholder="Adres e-mail" id="ad-email" required />
                    <input type="submit" name="#" id="send" value="ZAPISUJĘ    →">
                </div>
                
            </div>
            -->
            <!--New code-->
            
            <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
                
            <div class="indicates-required"><span class="asterisk">*</span>zeigt erforderlich an</div>
            <div class="mc-field-group email-btn text-3">
                
                <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" placeholder="Email Address *" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL">
            </div>
            <div class="mc-field-group text-3">
                
                <input type="text" value="" name="FNAME" placeholder="Name" class="" id="mce-FNAME">
            </div>
            <div class="mc-field-group text-3">
                
                <input type="text" value="" name="LNAME" placeholder="Vorname" class="" id="mce-LNAME">
            </div>
            <div class="mc-field-group text-3">
                <input type="text" value="" name="UNTERNEHME" placeholder="Unternehmen" class="" id="mce-UNTERNEHME">
            </div>
            <div class="mc-field-group">
                

                <textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="NACHRICHT" class="text-3" form="usrform" id="mce-NACHRICHT" placeholder="Nachricht">Nachricht
                    </textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="accept">
                <input type="checkbox" name="#" value="true" id="check" required>
                <label for="check"><span class="checkbox-box"></span><span class="checkbox-label">Ja, ich möchte aktuelle News und Aktionen erhalten
                        <a href="#" target="_blank"></a></span></label>
            </div>
                <div id="mce-responses" class="clear">
                    <div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display:none"></div>
                    <div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display:none"></div>
                </div>    <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
                <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" aria-hidden="true"><input type="text" name="b_da98377a6d05e2f01558d3e04_67aaab10f0" tabindex="-1" value=""></div>
                <div class="clear"><input type="submit" value="Abonnieren" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button-form"></div>

                </div>


            </div>
    </form>
    </div>
    </div>
    
    <!--End mc_embed_signup-->
                

            
        
    
</body>

</html>
```

So the endpoint does not go to Mailchimp, instead goes to wp-admin/admin-ajax.php
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: So are there any errors in the developer console in the browser? What does not work exactly, it is a bit unclear. The form shows up? When you submit it fails??

Comment: it points to endpoint admin-ajax.php instead of Mailchimp. So the submit button does not work when clicked. Preview on DevTools say: {action_status: false, message: "API key cannot be blank"}